# Is it more effective to use OLAP for OBIEE in terms of performance?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, olap, obiee

We have been using simple date warehouse for banking, that loads bulk data every night while the system is off, and connected to Obiee via Administration tool. It is working fine till now.

Recently, we have been discussing about moving to OLAP for our Data Warehouse since by definition it seems OLAP is most suitable for data retrieving even though it requires one more step to develop dimensions and measure facts in Analytics Workspace. And some sources say that queries will take more time to return results when OLAP is used. If there are some developers who switched from usual dwh development to implementing OLAP in it, do you recommend it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it simply: If the data source configuration and model are rubbish, then it doesn't matter at all if you go for a dimensional model.
I've seen flat-table-based models which performed like crazy and "OLAP models" which were slow beyond believe. Nothing is a fix-it-all solution. Never believe that slapping a new badge on something will solve a problem. You need to think about it and architect properly and accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for the feedback. I was thinking if time that should be spent to build this OLAP based model is worth trying. It seems the only way to find out is to build it and see the difference.

Comment: "normally" you're way faster with analytically oriented models like star schemas, yes.

Comment: You mean OLAP based models, right? I haven't used this one, so I may be confusing star schema in rpd and star schema in OLAP

Comment: Star Schema. The Data Modelling concept. It's something tangible and defined. "OLAP" doesn't mean anything specific or defined in terms of data modelling.